# How to sync Mysql Database Between Continents?

Tags: php, mysql, database, cdn, amazon-route53

i think what i am planning is very interesting :) I am planning a world wide global web project, but it would be too slow for a europe centered database if someone wants to reach for example from australia to germany. Well A average page would have 1,5 - 2,5 mb pagesize(mostly 80% images), fine lets say i have cdn across continents with amazon or google etc. But it is still slow for me to connect to the europe center.

Well **The idea** is what if i would to use services like amazon route 53 or google cloud dns to determine multi servers(same cms software script duplicated) for different locations like usa, germany,south asia. This is going to be really fast, because we had continent based servers.

**Problem**?
But i need either a new high cloud style tech like global single database can be reached really fast from locations which i dont have too much budget for it, still just say if its possible:) Or i need to sync data between databases from different continents. If one of them changes the others should change too, if 1 server goes down for 1 hour, it should also sync new datas.

**End**:
Todo that if i need to reinvent the wheel again, yes i want it :) its worth for that kind of speed. Help me, what is your ideas about such server plan, how to do that...

Comment: the internet is kind of fast, hosting location vs user location is really not an issue

Comment: I too have a similar requirement, did anyone found any solution to this, if yes please share.

Answer (score -1):

Nice i am going to meet larry ellison from onaracle tomorrow. Looks like poor people doesnt get answers for their global projects when they dont buy product supports from companies like onaracle, microgates, applasia :)

Comment: I too have a similar requirement, did anyone found any solution to this, if yes please share.